# Filtering table result based on user input in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, react-hooks

current functionality is
data will be loaded only when user click on `submit` button. if he does not put any `filter` then all data will be loaded.

```
 const submit = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const param = {
            ...(certificateNo && { certificateNo: certificateNo }),
            ...(protoColNo && { protoColNo: protoColNo }),
            ...(requestStatus && { requestStatus: requestStatus }),
            ...(sponser && { sponser: sponser }),
            ...(country && { country: country }),
            ...(noOfSubjects && { noOfSubjects: noOfSubjects }),
            ...(startDate && { startDate: startDate }),
            ...(endDate && { endDate: endDate }),
        };
        console.log(param);
        const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/certificates', {
            params: param,
        });
        console.log(data);
        setFlag(true);
        setResponse(data);
    };
```

now I have a requirement. when `page` gets loaded data without any `filter` should be loaded on the page. means user can see the data on page when he visits, later he can apply filter after click on submit button.

I am thinking to use `useEffect()` , can you guide how to do that.

I have put here the next and previous code

```
 const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
 const [lastPage, setLastPage] = useState(0);




const next = () => {
        if (page <= lastPage) {
          setPage(page + 1);
          fetchData(page);
        }
      }
```

and for previous

```
const prev = () => {

        if (page >= 1) {
          setPage(page - 1);
        }
      }
```

Below is buttons which I created

```
  <ul className="pagination">
          <li className="page-item">
            <button onClick={prev}>Previous</button>
          </li>
          <li className="page-item">
            <button onClick={next}>Next</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: After clicking on submit are you sending an API request which could return the filtered data or do you just want to filter the data stored in the state?

Comment: You need a new state `const [ filter, setFitler ] = useState({});` which would store the details of the the form as you update it. When you submit the form you would call a function that would `filter` over the data and return a new set of data where the values of the properties in the data match the values in the filter object. That data would then be used for your table.

Comment: @Gnanavel at the time of page load entire data will be loaded on UI. user can filter later. so basically need to filter data stored on state.

Comment: @Andy will I have to make API call every time user click on submit button?  can we do something so that this can be handled at UI level?

Comment: @NiharikaS Not necessarily. You would have to download _all_ of the data which, depending on its size, might not be as optimal as sending the filter state to a server which uses that information to send back the correct data. How many rows of data are in your dataset?

Comment: around 10krows. I am thinking to use pagination. so in beginning data will be loaded with pagination.

Comment: 10K is probably too much. I recommend a simple backend that can do the filtering for you when you supply an endpoint with a filter object.

Comment: thank you @andy . I have backend API ready for filter. could you please guide modification on above code?

Comment: You should stop editing your question as the current edit is completely different from the question you originally asked. @NiharikaS

Comment: @Andy ya Andy.. I understood. sorry for that...I thought edit will make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have your backend filter mechanism. Just create a state which contains all the filters data. Create a function `fetchData` which do the fetching works. When users visit for the first time `fetchData` inside `useEffect` will be called and at that time all filters will be empty so all data should be loaded. After applying filters and if the user submits the button fetchData function inside `submit` event will be called. And for the paging mechanism maintain a another state. If you want to fetch records of next page just increase the `page` state

```
const [filters,setFilters]=useState({
    certificateNo:"",
    protoColNo:"",
    requestStatus:"",
    sponser:"",
    country:"",
    noOfSubjects:"",
    startDate:"",
    endDate:"",
})
const [page,setPage] = useState(1)
const fetchData = async (page)=>{
    const {
        certificateNo,
        protoColNo,
        requestStatus,
        sponser,
        country,
        noOfSubjects,
        startDate,
        endDate,
    } = filters

    const param = {
        ...(certificateNo && { certificateNo: certificateNo }),
        ...(protoColNo && { protoColNo: protoColNo }),
        ...(requestStatus && { requestStatus: requestStatus }),
        ...(sponser && { sponser: sponser }),
        ...(country && { country: country }),
        ...(noOfSubjects && { noOfSubjects: noOfSubjects }),
        ...(startDate && { startDate: startDate }),
        ...(endDate && { endDate: endDate }),
    };
    console.log(param);
    const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/certificates?page=${page}`, {
        params: param,
    });
    setFlag(true);
    setResponse(data);
}
const submit = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchData(page)
};

useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData(page)
},[page])
```

Comment: I have put the code above. could you please guide, modification over above.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh...actually requirement is even without user click on submit, all data should be there. means at landing time user can see the data. later he can apply filter and submit the button then he will see only that data..

Comment: With that many records it sounds like you should implement infinite scrolling. [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/infinite-scrolling/) has a good implementation of this.

Comment: @NiharikaS I have updated my answer please do check

Comment: Thank you @Gnanavel . Let me try the same.

Comment: @Gnanavel Its working. I have one question where I have to update setPage() inside the fetchData()?

Comment: I have added remaining code in question in bottom

Comment: @NiharikaS You don't need to use `setPage()` inside `fetchData()`. Because `useEffect will` run whenever component renders for first time and `page` state value changes. If you click on page number 2(in pagination) you are calling next function which will increment the `page` state value which causes component to rerender and fetchData inside useEffect will we executed. So you also don't need to use `fetchData()` inside `next` and `prev` function

Comment: Thank you @Gnanavel . Thank you so much.